# Diferença entre métodos private e final

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, método, private

Estudando sobre métodos e classes final no livro "Como programar em Java 6 ed." do Deitel me deparei com a seguinte proposição:

> Os métodos declarados private são implicitamente final, porque é impossível sobrescrevê-los em uma subclasse *(embora a subclasse possa declarar um novo método com a mesma assinatura do método private na superclasse)*.

Não entendi essa última parte em itálico. Declarar um método com a mesma assinatura não é o mesmo que sobrescrever?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vou ser direto,

> (embora a subclasse possa declarar um novo método com a mesma
>   assinatura do método private na superclasse)

**Não entendi essa última parte em itálico. Declarar um método com a mesma assinatura não é o mesmo que sobrescrever?**

Não, porque **dentro da super classe** as chamadas dos métodos private, que são feitas dentro da superclasse ainda vão continuar apontando para o método `private` da propria super classe, mesmo que exista um igual na subclasse.

**Super Classe**

```
public class SuperClasse {
    public int processar(int x, int y){
         return somar(x,y);
     }

     private int somar(int x, int y){
          return x+y;
     }
}
```

**Classe Filha**

```
public class SubClasse extends SuperClasse {
    private int somar(int x, int y){
         return x*y;
     }
}
```

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SubClasse sub = new SubClasse();
    int resultado = sub.processar(10, 5);
    System.out.println(resultado+"");
}
```

Faça o teste e veja a saida.

Como deduzimos que não houve sobreescrita? porque se houvesse a sobreescrita o resultado seria **50**. Como não houve, o processamento fez a soma. 
Quer saber como sobreescrever? transforme os métodos soma em `public`. Rode e veja o resultado novamente.

Answer (score 15):

Não é o mesmo se o método é declarado como `private`. Este modificador indica que o método só deve existir dentro da classe. É algo interna dela e ninguém mais deve ter acesso, nem mesmo os tipos derivados dela.

Se o método só existe nela, ele não pode ser visto ou acessado pelos tipos derivados, qualquer método que possua a mesma assinatura é um novo método. A sobrescrita só ocorreria se o método existisse para o tipo derivado. E mesmo assim se não fosse `final`. Imagino que entenda que o `final` também impede a sobrescrita.

O que talvez não saiba que ele não impede que exista um método de assinatura igual. Só que neste caso ocorrerá a sobreposição. Na maior parte dos casos não é o que se deseja.

Isto tem a ver com polimorfismo.

Quando o método é público e virtual, onde se espera um tipo mais genérico pode usar o tipo mais específico e o método deste tipo é que será chamado.

Quando o método não é virtual, o método que será chamado é sempre o do tipo genérico. Não ocorre o polimorfismo. Aí você pensa que o método com mesma assinatura no tipo derivado será chamado, mas ele não será. Ele só pode ser chamado diretamente.

```
class A {
    public metodo() { System.out.println("A"); }
}
class B extends A {
    @override public metodo() { System.out.println("B"); }
}
class Principal {
    public static main() {
        B x = new B();
        teste(x); // imprime B porque B é derivado de A e o método é virtual
        A y = new A();
        teste(y); // imprime A
    }
    public static teste(A x) {
        x.metodo();
    }
}
```

Sem polimorfismo:

```
class A {
    private metodo() { System.out.println("A"); }
}
class B extends A {
    public metodo() { System.out.println("B"); }
}
class Principal {
    public static main() {
        B x = new B();
        testeB(x); //Imprime B
        teste(x); //por ser privado, é final, e o compilador não tenta acessar o tipo derivado
        // não vai funcionar, teste() só consegue acessar o método de A, que é privado
        A y = new A();
        teste(y); //não vai funcionar
    }
    public static teste(A x) {
        x.metodo(); //não compila, o método não existe, métodos privados não são acessíveis fora da classe
    }
    public static testeB(B x) {
        x.metodo();
    }
}
```

Note que aqui os métodos possuem a mesma assinatura mas um existe privativamente e ou outro publicamente. Eles não se confundem. Não dá para sobrescrever algo que não se pode sequer ver. Se é privado o compilador vai ignorar o método.

Sem polimorfismo mas tudo público

```
class A {
    final public metodo() { System.out.println("A"); }
}
class B extends A {
    public metodo() { System.out.println("B"); }
}
class Principal {
    public static main() {
        B x = new B();
        testeB(x); //Imprime B, óbvio, não tem como errar
        teste(x); //Imprime A, não há polimorfismo, ele só entende o que há em A
        A y = new A();
        teste(y); //imprime A
    }
    public static teste(A x) {
        x.metodo();
    }
    public static testeB(B x) {
        x.metodo();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/PrivateFinal.java).

Comment: Existe o modificador "virtual" em java?

Comment: Ele é o *default*. Não usou nada, é virtual.

Answer (score 11):

A palavra chave `final` significa que o método definido com ela não poderá ser sobrescrito em uma subclasse.

Métodos privados são apenas acessiveis dentro da classe definida, logo não é possível acessar/sobrescrever um método `private` em uma subclasse.

> Declarar um método com a mesma assinatura não é o mesmo que
>   sobrescrever?

Isso depende onde o método é declarado.

Quando existe dois ou mais métodos com mesmas assinaturas(parâmetros de tipos diferentes) na mesma classe isso é chamado de sobrecarga ou `overloading`.

Quando um método tem uma assinatura igual e é herdado de um super classe é chamado de sobrescrita ou `override` ou seja a subclasse pode mudar/sobrescrever o comportamento/implementação do método fornecido pela super classe, claro desde que esse método não tenha sido marcado como `final`.

Answer (score 9):

> Declarar um método com a mesma assinatura não é o mesmo que sobrescrever?

Se você declarar métodos com a mesma assinatura porém em classes completamente diferentes, isso não é sobrescrever, são apenas dois métodos com a mesma assinatura, mas que não tem relação um com o outro.

A sobrescrita somente pode ocorrer em um relacionamento de herança ou extensão entre classes e interfaces, ou seja, uma classe pode sobrescrever um método da superclasse ou da interface que ela implementa, desde que esse método esteja visível para a subclasse, caso contrário, é o mesmo que dizer que existem dois métodos com a mesa assinatura que não se relacionam, como o exemplo das classes distintas.

Answer (score 3):

Private indica que a propriedade ou método **não é herdado** pelas classes filhas e somente a classe proprietária pode acessar a propriedade ou método.

Final indica que a classe filha pode herdar e acessar (acessar propriedades e métodos herdados, não as propriedades ou métodos da classe pai), mas **não pode modificar** ou sobrescrever. *É só isso*.

O que passa disso é meramente didático.